# Fixing the pins in a flex cable

Tags: cables, ribbon-cable, fpc, ffc, flexible

This is a flex cable from a kindle that connects the motherboard to the lcd.
The pins at the edge are broken and not making any contact with the connector.

Is there any salvation for this?
If there's no solution will a universal flex cable work as long it has the same amount of pins and pitch?

[image: Flex cable]

Comment: What is a "universal flex cable" - other than wishful thinking, perhaps?

Comment: something like this: https://media.rs-online.com/t_large/F7635596-01.jpg

Comment: You've posted a link to a photo instead of a link to the datasheet. The photo looks like a 0.1" ribbon. Your post photo doesn't.

Comment: I can clearly see the connector tab is destroyed.  If you can get another cable you might be able to fix the problem.  The two outside pins seems to be large current, look at the width of the tracks.  See if the cable you can find also have this.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, these are **tiny** connections that can't be fixed easily and reliably in my opinion. While the cable itself appears to be custom, the connection pattern looks familiar.

I would try to find an of-the-shelf cable with that exact connection pattern. Chances are that the traces of a  an of-the-shelf cable won't fit the requirements, e. g. for transmission line impedance or current capacity. But I would give it a try.

The connection pattern looks like one form Molex I recently worked with. So maybe an of-the-shelf cable like this could work: https://www.molex.com/en-us/products/part-detail/150150251

However, you need to double check the pin count and if "same sided" contacts will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
This operation requires a microscope and medical needles or similar instruments.

Comment: @unknown777, I think Peter is suggesting that by trimming the edge of the ribbon you will be able to insert it into the connector a little further to allow the contacts to touch undamaged portions of the ribbon pads. You'll probably get one chance at this so be prepared to spend 30 to 60 minutes setting up a jig to hold the cable and straight edge precisely in place and get a new blade to make the cut.

Comment: By "short circuit" you like a little sparks or something more dangerous?